# How can I restrict dnsmasq to only reply to specific client DNS requests?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I am looking at using a dnsmasq server to easily serve up some local ad-hoc hostnames and also provide recursive DNS for the local clients.

However, the dnsmasq service appears to always allow any client to look up DNS entries once it is configured as a recursive DNS server.

Is there a way to restrict the dnsmasq service to only allow requests from local clients, say something like 192.168.0.0/16 and 127.0.0.0/8 and perhaps even a few, select, public IPs?

I could do it with iptables, but it would be much preferable if I could keep the DNS-relevant configuration local to dnsmasq.

Answer (score 0):

you can restrict the interface that dnsmasq listens on (say for example your local network):

this specifies only listen on eth0:

```
interface=eth0
```

and this specifies only listen on a particular address (in this case 192.168.1.1):

```
listen-address:192.168.1.1
```

you can also specify an interface not to listen on:

```
except-interface=eth1
```

you can repeat the line for more than one interface.

**AMENDMENT**

apologies, i've re-read your question and don't believe my answer is particularly helpful, you want to restrict access to dns (in dnsmasq conf), not restrict where/how your dhcp leases are handed out. I don't know how to do this in the dnsmasq conf file, so i'll let someone else answer. I'll leave my original answer here, just on the off chance it's useful to anyone.

Comment: ps. for helping yourself, the file /etc/dnsmasq.conf that is installed by default (at least on my debian box), contains a lot of examples and is worth a read, just if that's helpful.

Comment: Thank you for answering, although, as you noted, I am still without an answer to my original question.

Comment: Yep don't mark mine as accepted, if someone knows you'll get a response hopefully. If I discover something I'll also come back.